# prevent bootstrap accordion th

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

Morning ... how can stop bootstrap (3.3.7) accordion to change url?
data-target doesn't work for me.

My url looks like this: `http://www.example.com/?content=abc` because I use php include function. Once I click on accordion pan it looks like `http://www.example.com/#aaa`. It is obvious that a reload will not work anymore.

I found a solution for bootstrap tabs but it doesn't work with accordion.

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function () {
$org_url = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
$url_hash = $(this).attr('href');
window.location.href = $org_url + $url_hash;
return false;});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks